# Syntax error highlighting "print" as an error

Tags: python, syntax-error

When I run this code it gives me a syntax error highlighting "print" as an error. Can't figure out why it's doing this:

def skipline (value):
if value >= 3 :
return(" This person is eligible to kip the line")
else:
returne (" This person is not eligible to skip the line")
value =int(input("Enter a clearance value")
print(skipline(value))

[image]

Comment: That's because your indent is wrong

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code. Please include the text of the error message, and mention which Python version you're using.

Comment: I have just added a picture with the error msg. I am using Python 3.6.4 version

Answer (score 0):

There was indentation mistakes and change `returne` to `return`. Here is the correct code:

```
def skipline(value):
    if value >= 3:
        return("Eligible")
    else:
        return("Not eligible")
value = int(input("Enter value"))
print(skipline(value))
```